# ffmpeg wmv to mp4 and synchronous add a logo image

Tags: ffmpeg

The script I use to add a logo:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i test.png \
       -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; \
       [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a \ 
       -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

The command I use to convert video. (With this command, synchronize your webm and mp4 and get the picture.)

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis \
       outputwebm.webm -c:v libx264 -crf 35 outputmp4.mp4 \ 
       -vf "thumbnail,scale=640:360" -frames:v 1 outputpng.png
```

I want to add the logo image as synchronous.

The command I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M \
       -c:a libvorbis outputwebm.webm -c:v libx264 \ 
       -crf 35 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i test.png \ 
       -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; \
       [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a \ 
       -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest outputmp4.mp4 \ 
       -vf "thumbnail,scale=640:360" -frames:v 1 outputpng.png
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Group all inputs at the front of the command and remove the encoding for the temp MP4 file.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i test.png -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis outputwebm.webm -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest outputmp4.mp4 -vf "thumbnail,scale=640:360" -frames:v 1 outputpng.png
```

If your PNG has greater resolution than the WMV then you'll need to map the video for the webm and png outputs.